# Installing libcouchbase on CentOS

Tags: couchbase

I was installing libcouchbase and libvbucket on CentOS Linux

I was following the instruction on this page 
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-c-1.0/linux_and_mac.html

vbucket was installed successfully.
However I was installing libcouchbase and while i was doing the config part, I got an error message :

checking for libevent... no
configure: error: libevent2 is required for libcouchbase.

What is wrong with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install libevent. You can download it here:

https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.17-stable.tar.gz

Comment: Now I am getting new error... cannot locate memcached/vbucket.h!

Comment: I am really stuck on this vbucket thing for whole day.. my mental is about to be gone lol

Comment: I've talked with other people who have had trouble with this too so your not alone. Do you have couchbase installed on your dev machine. The reason is that that vbucket.h file is part of the couchbase installation. That's why you have to do the /opt/couchbase prefix. If it's not installed then you can install the couchbase version of memcached. You can grab it at github.com/membase/memcached. You can either do a make install on it or you can just build it and provide libcouchbase with your own a prefix to the build location. Let me know if your having any other problems.

Comment: OMG Solved.. I downloaded "Memcache for membase" and instaleld it and it works fine... I think you must let people know that installing "memcache" wont do the trick. It must be "memcache-for-membase"

Comment: We're working on getting the documentation updated. Glad you got things working.